# Input in a cycle (Python)

Tags: python

I'm learning Python as my first language and now I trying to resolve this problem:

I have to make a loop where I ask the user which elements from a list they want to remove and then remove the elements selected. The loop stops only when the user insert a specific number that corresponds to the length of the list increased by 1 (so I won't have any problem).

I have another problem related to this:

```
elements_list = ['a','b','c','d']
length_list = len(elements_list)

for i in range(0, length_list):
    print (str(i) + str(')') + elements_list[i])
```

This will print the list starting with 0:

> 0) a
>   1) b
>   2) c
>   3) d

What do I have to do if I want the list start with 1? (if I use 1 instead of 0 in the range it doesn't print the first element of the list)

Comment: If you want it to start from 1, simply add 1 to the printed string: `print (str(i+1) + str(')') + elements_list[i])`

Answer (score 3):

In Python, lists can be iterated directly, and `enumerate` is used to generate indexes.  Its optional second parameter gives a starting number:

```
>>> elements = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for i,v in enumerate(elements,1):
...   print('{}) {}'.format(i,v))
...
1) a
2) b
3) c
4) d
```

If using Python 3.6+, formatting output is even more simple using f-strings:

```
>>> elements = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for i,v in enumerate(elements,1):
...   print(f'{i}) {v}')
...
1) a
2) b
3) c
4) d
```

Refs:

- [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a 1 in the range, then subtract a 1 from the index

```
elements_list=['a','b','c','d']
lenght_list=len(elements_list)
for i in range(1, lenght_list+1):
     print (str(i) + str(')') + elements_list[i-1])
```

Edit: TheoretiCAL's approach is even more straight forward, simply adding 1 to the print statement achieves the same thing.

Comment: It's easier than I was expecting, really thanks all of you guys! What about the input request? I really don't figuring out how make it